# raise Button click from UserControl to my form (asp.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, user-controls

can you please help me and tell me why my code is incorrect.
I want to create a UserControl that will be a registration form.
In this control, I have a button, when the button is clicked, I want the server to redirect to another page.
Here's my code:

control.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class ControlFormulaire : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;// it could be named differently obviously
    protected void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               if (this.ButtonClicked != null)
                    ButtonClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

form.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SubscribForm.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(SubscribForm_ButtonClicked); 
}

void SubscribForm_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
}
```

and that's my form.aspx:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Form" Src="~/ControlFormulaire.ascx"%>
<uc:Form ID="SubscribForm" runat="Server" MinVal="1" MaxVal="10" />
```

Comment: Why do you need page_lod in userControl? I think you should remove it. Also you should change `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SubscribForm.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(SubscribForm_ButtonClicked); 
}
` ----- to ------ `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    this.SubscribForm.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(SubscribForm_ButtonClicked); 
}
}
`. If still (after following above instructions) you face same problem please share your button creation code.

Comment: I've sent you my files at your email (samiakram@live.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
public partial class ControlFormulaire : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;// it could be named differently obviously
    protected void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           ButtonClicked();
    }

    private void ButtonClicked()
    {
       if (ButtonClicked!= null)
       {
           ButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ControlFormulaire.ButtonClicked+= new EventHandler(SubscribForm_ButtonClicked);
}

void SubscribForm_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
}
```

Comment: huMpty duMpty, thank you for your answer but I can'tunderstand it. It's fail at compilation. maybe there is a syntax error?

Comment: Erreur 3 the type 'WebApplication1.ControlFormulaire' already have a definition for 'ButtonClicked'

Comment: well, if you look at the code that you sent me, you can see that both the event and the method have the same name. I also tried to change the name of the event, but nothing happened. the thread doesn't enter the validateButtonClick method

Comment: I'm so sorry...It didn't worked because of something else. i put a RequestFieldValidator on a textbox. so I had to write something on it. I realy sorry...

Comment: @user1811956 On behalf of SO and huMpty being member fellow. i assure you that you do not have to apologize for your mistakes, it just shows your goodness if you do, but you do not need to, when you have already tried to solve your problem at your own. You sent me code so I need to apologize that I was not available to check your code at that time.

Answer (score 0):

```
this line is the key or the custom click event ignores updatepanel 
// ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);
```

and note the IPostBackEventHandler part in page definition

```
in this example ordinary button and a custom click event div work together inside an update panel
```

public partial class tmp2 : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler
{

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        div1.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "ClickDiv");
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += "1";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
protected void Div1_Click()
{

    div1.InnerHtml += "b";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();

}



public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))
    {

        if (eventArgument == "ClickDiv")
        {

            Div1_Click();

        }

    }

}`

}